# How did $y_i$ go missing in the final equation?

Tags: svm

I am following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7tC9MpVr9I&t=223) on Support Vector Machines.  Could someone explain to me how $y_i$ go missing in the final equation?  Much appreciated.

[image: imge]

Comment: I would assume because $y_i=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo. The correct formula should be
$$f(\mathbf x)=\operatorname{sign}\left(\sum_i \alpha_iy_i\mathbf x_i^T\mathbf x+b\right)$$

Comment: Thanks!  I really appreciate it.